# Would the alchemy gate of people be empty while god was inside Father?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood, fullmetal-alchemist-manga

If someone tried human transmutation and went in front of their gate, while God was inside Father, would they see emptiness inside their gate?